# Add a favicon to redmine theme

Tags: redmine, favicon

redmine uses the favicon placed at `/usr/share/redmine/public/favicon.ico`

I found a lot of code snippets using `cd /usr/share/redmine/; grep -HR favicon app/`

```
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:  def favicon
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:    "<link rel='shortcut icon' href='#{favicon_path}' />".html_safe
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:  # Returns the path to the favicon
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:  def favicon_path
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:    icon = (current_theme && current_theme.favicon?) ? current_theme.favicon_path : '/favicon.ico'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:  # Returns the full URL to the favicon
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:  def favicon_url
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:    path = favicon_path
app/views/journals/index.builder:  xml.icon    favicon_url
app/views/common/feed.atom.builder:  xml.icon    favicon_url
app/views/layouts/base.html.erb:<%= favicon %>
```

But no luck finding more info about how to set the `favicon_path` or `favicon_url`.

### Workaround:

I added a small javascript in the theme folder: `javascripts/theme.js`:

```
document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

function changeFavicon(src) {
 var link = document.createElement('link'),
     oldLink = document.getElementById('dynamic-favicon');
 link.id = 'dynamic-favicon';
 link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
 link.href = src;
 if (oldLink) {
  document.head.removeChild(oldLink);
 }
 document.head.appendChild(link);
}

changeFavicon('../themes/freifunk-red-andy/images/favicon.ico');
```

(But that workaround only works if the visitor uses javascript)

Comment: Please don't just ask questions to answer them on your own. While this is acceptable sometimes for well-defined problems, it doesn't absolve you from asking a good question and providing a good answer. Most of the time, these things are better placed on your own blog though...

Comment: My workaround wasn't an answer. Your answer really seems to be what I couldn't find anywhere documented

Comment: @HolgerJust: I wonder what you refer to: The community benefits from having a growing store of useful question/answer articles on this site, so everyone should be encouraged to do exactly that: answer your own questions if you found a solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redmine automatically loads the first file it finds inside the `favicon` sub-directory of your theme. Thus, if you put your favicon into e.g. `favicon/favicon.ico`, it will be automatically used by Redmine.

Comment: Great, this worked! I only had to restart apache otherwise the old pages keep cached

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is ambiguous as there are 2 places you have to consider depending what you really want to do.

If you want to change the favicon of ...

1. ... an **additionally installed theme** you have to go with @Holger Just 's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27440983/887930) and copy your own favicon into the folder `redmine/htdocs/public/themes/YOURTHEME/favicon/` (overwrite an existing `favicon.ico` or create the folder `favicon` inside the theme's folder if necessary).
2. ... the **standard preinstalled redmine theme** you have to copy your own favicon into the folder `redmine/htdocs/public` (overwriting the existing `favicon.ico`)